# Bootstrap Span offsets and background-color, how to avoid coloring the offset?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to position these spans in the middle:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XHhG.png

and I can do that by adding an offset1 to them:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbr8T.png

Now, my questions is: How can I prevent the offset from being colored too. Please excuse me if my question is too vague.

HTML:

```
  <div class="span10" style="margin: 0 auto;background-color:#FFDDDD;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span2 offset1" style="text-align: right">
        <h1 style="">RWCO</h1>
        <h3>Bis: 11. März</h3>
      </div>
          <div class="span7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit a...`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply the background color only to the divs (in this case span2 and maybe span7?) you want to have the colored background. 
In the example you posted you applied the background to the span10 that act as container and it is normal that you get the background applied to the entire block...

Try this:

```
<div class="span10" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span2 offset1" style="text-align: right; background-color:#FFDDDD;">
        <h1 style="">RWCO</h1>
        <h3>Bis: 11. März</h3>
      </div>
          <div class="span7" style="background-color:#FFDDDD;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit a...`
```

By the way, I would advice you to apply styles via classes and not inline...

Comment: Don't worry, the styles will go into classes once the layout is kinda finished. After following your advice, it now looks like this: http://puu.sh/19Khb

I wanted to have them as one area though, or at least both should have the same height.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a span1 before the span2.

(You may have to just leave a space in the div for the span1. Otherwise the browser will collapse this div.)

(If this answer works then just leave a comment with whether you had to leave a space in the div or it worked without the space also.)

Comment: Now it looks like this, adding a space has no effect it seems: http://puu.sh/19K0R

Comment: you added a separate div with span1 before the div with span2 right?